# Why does my taxonomy have a category style div id?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, tags

I created two custom taxonomies. I created them using identical code and then finding and replacing the "name" with "name2".

I've then looked at the post type page and there are two tag boxes to choose tags in.

However, one div is called "namediv" and the other is "tagdiv-name2".

This would suggest that one is a category and one is a taxonomy.

I know that categories are kind of a taxonomy, but why is my custom taxonomy taking the form of a category?

Thanks,

Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress uses the `category`-style meta box to handle `hierarchical => true` taxonomies and the post tags meta box for "flat" taxonomies. The CSS in the admin UI is just ... "grown", so names like those don't change until they really need to. `category` and `post_tag` btw are just `name`s for `_builtin => true` taxonomies.

Comment: Ah - I'd assumed they shared a root, but hadn't looked into it. Cheers for the sharp and perfect answer :)